# What’s good on the menu today?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Is this phrase about something delicious on the menu, about their best meal, or about something standard and normal?

> **What’s good on the menu today?**

Comment: Menus list food items, "What's good" on one refers to those items.

Comment: It suggests a rotating menu, and day to day, different things will be good

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be about any of those things.  How it would be understood could depend on the wider context.  For example if you were visiting a restaurant for the first time they might tell you the "speciality of the restaurant".  If you went regularly, they might tell you about something that was not usually on the menu.

Answer (score 2):

It could be a question which refers to all three of your ideas however it's most likely to be about your first idea. It's likely a question about "something delicious" since it's referring to a good thing on the menu today. It is most likely simply to be about the most positive thing on the menu on this particular day out of all days.

It could potentially be about a comparison between something good and something standard and normal. The context of this question would be important in order to know if this question is a comparison to previous standard and normal options from the past. Without a reference to the past things on the menu it's not so likely to be about a comparison between good, standard and normal things on today's menu.

It's unlikely to be about their best meal as it's not a specific question about their best meal. This question is specifically about today's menu only it's therefore unlikely to be about menus from any days other than today. In this context their best meal is unlikely to be specifically in today's menu although it could be in today's menu. Today's menu could have their best meal on it if the menu has been the same for several days or longer.

This question is essentially asking for a recommendation from someone else about what to choose to eat today it's most likely about the tastiness and quality of the good food in the meal to be eaten today. In some rare occasions this question could be about ethically good things on today's menu as well. For example if there are Vegan/Vegetarian options which are sourced ethically in order to be 'good' or better for the animals in the area of the food's source. Many things can be considered to be good or not by different people from their own subjective perspectives.

Source Used:

1. [On today’s menu: All kinds of good](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ado0lcFkl-8) "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ado0lcFkl-8".